# 2 legged oauth to send an email from a pod in GKE

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I need some help in determining the Oauth client app type **(internal or external)** and `grant_type` to generate an access_token from a pod running in GKE.

I have implemented a backend *email-service (which is running in a **GKE** cluster) to send an  email. I have created a email-oauth-client with app_type as “internal” as this is going to be used only by my backend
**email-service.**

First time, I generated the access_token and refresh_token manually in https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and added the logic in the  backend email-service to generate the access_token using the refresh_token whenever the access_token is expired.

Since, the email-oauth-client is an internal app, grant is revoked after 7days and the refresh_token is not valid after 7days. So, I have to generate the  access_token every week manually in the oauthplayground and use it.

I have also tried to use client_crendential grant_type. But, google oauth server doesn’t  support this grant_type.

Could anyone please let me know which grant_type that I can use to get an **access_token** without prompting for user consent? I appreciate your help.

I tried to use **2legged** oauth flow to avoid user consent. But, GCP doesn't support this flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh tokens expire after seven days if the application is in testing mode.

Go to google cloud console for your spp under oauth2 consent screen on set it to production.   Your refresh token won't expire anymore

Note: you are using three legged oauth2 not two legged

## client types

1. installed app consent screen runs on the machine
2. web app runs consent screen runs on user browser
3. mobile consent screen on mobile devices
4. service account for service to server communication with pre-authorized Access. No user consent prompt.  only works with workspace domain wide deligation for Gmail.

Internal is something for workspace only

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for the response. When i tried to make it 'In Production' status, GCP ask me to submit this app for verification. This verification process requires privacy policy, terms_and_condition docs and youtube video about the usage etc. Should i have to use service_account client type to avoid this verification step?

Comment: Gmail Api Service accounts only work with Google workspace domain emails not standard google account gmail address. See Point 4.  If your trying to connect to a Users gmail account then you need to use Oauth2 and go though the verification process.   If its a google workspace domain email then you can use a service account and configure domain wide delegation.